# Vector Space Question

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing some of MIT's old problem sets for linear algebra and came across this question:

The link is here if you wanna see a better formatted version of the question (1g) http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Spring12/ps3_sp12_sol.pdf

True or False: The difference a = x1 - x2 between any two solutions x1 and x2 to Ax = b is a vector that belongs to the nullspace N(A). Apply the rule A(x + uy) = Ax + uAy to A(x1 - x2) to answer the question.

From my understanding, if A is m x n and x is n dimensions, then the difference a is an n-dimensional solution. However N(A) is a subspace in the m-dimensional plane consisting of Ax. Thus a cannot be in N(A) since the dimensions are different. Of course Aa is in N(A) but not just a.

In other words any solution x to Ax = b does not lie in the subspace of Ax. The subspace is the graphical representation of all combinations of the columns of A in R^m.

Also I don't quite understand the answer that is given. Could someone explain the intuition behind it?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: $A(x_1-x_2)=Ax_1 - Ax_2 = b - b = 0$

Comment: I think you got column space and nullspace confused.

Comment: What is the difference. I thought null space is essentially column space for b = 0.

Comment: The null space is $\operatorname{Ker}(A)=\{x \in \Bbb R^n \mid Ax = 0 \}$ whereas the column space $\operatorname{Im}(A)=\{Ax \mid x \in \Bbb R^m\}$. The null space is the set of vectors whose image by $A$ are $0$ whereas the column space is the set of the images of all the vectors by $A$.

Comment: Ah okay I see what you're saying now.

Comment: @xavierm02 Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).